# not able to clean a repository.

Tags: git, debian

I am inside a repo. and was trying to compile a software and it failed. I tried again and came across this :-

```
$ git-buildpackage --git-ignore-branch
gbp:error: You have uncommitted changes in your source tree:
gbp:error: On branch experimental
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/experimental'.
Changes not staged for commit:
 (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
 (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   examples/Makefile.am

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

gbp:error: Use --git-ignore-new to ignore.
```

I then did :-

```
$git clean -f
```

and tried again but still got the same modified examples/Makefile.am error there, why ? Why didn't it clean it or put it back into the pristine state ?

Answer (score 1):

The build process seems to have modified the tracked file `examples/Makefile.am`.

The command `git clean -f` only cleans untracked files.  It doesn't revert modified files to their last recorded state in the repository.  To do the latter, use

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

to drop all local changes. (Beware!  It will drop all changes you did.)